# What do we call this kind of Summer Jackets?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image: back view][image: front view]

Is there any particular word for this type of Jacket?

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [hoodie](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hoodie).

> **hoodie** n.
>   1. (Clothing & Fashion) a hooded sweatshirt
>   <sup><sub>Collins English Dictionary</sub></sup>

Comment: Or could it be a *fleece*?

Comment: @WS2 Fleeces are similar, but normally made of thicker stuff than sweatshirts, and don't have a hood. The defining feature of the illustrated garment is the hood, together with the thinner material which can be seen in the linked large images.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, **windbreaker**

> a windbreaker or windcheater is a thin coat designed to resist wind chill and light rain, a lighter version of a jacket

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windbreaker)

Comment: In reply to Elian-Summer Jacket!Anyway thanks

Comment: @flinto Some windbreakers/windcheaters are specifically designed for the summer, like those you can see here http://www.alibaba.com/women%2527s-windcheater-promotion.html